# QGraphicsItem selection

Tags: qt, selection, qgraphicsitem

Does a simple method exist to select part of a QGraphicsItem (like for a selection, with a dashed border for example), despite its position in the `QGraphicsScene`

I've found `QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable` but it doesn't help me much.

Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't select a part of QGraphicsItem. You can select whole item. Usualy it will draw a dashed rectangle around itself when selected.

You can select item by:

```
QGraphicsItem::setSelected
```

or

```
QGraphicsScene::setSelectionArea
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to select it when you're clicking on it? If yes, you can override the `mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent event)` listener for this item, and use `setSelected()`. In Java (sorry about it), it would be something like:

```
@Override
public void mousePressEvent (QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent event) {
    if (event.button() == Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton) {
        this.setSelected(true);
    }
}
```

If you want to select it with a left button of course. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can call [QGraphicsScene::setSelectionArea(QPainter path, QTransform)](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qgraphicsscene.html#setSelectionArea), and later retrieve the area by calling selectionArea. However if you want to retrieve the items currently under selection, you will get only whole QGraphicsItems.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to use `ItemIsSelectable`:

```
QGraphicsRectItem* item = new QGraphicsRectItem(rect);
item->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);
graphicsScene->addItem(item);
```

You can then connect the `selectionChanged` signal to a slot:

```
connect(graphicsScene, &QGraphicsScene::selectionChanged, this, &MyWidget::itemClicked);
```

Note that `selectionChanged` is triggered on double click only, not on a single click.